# Create SQL file after submit form in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a data entry project, online web applications using PHP Codeigniter. There are more than 150 questions in my project, with user about 400.

I worried that with so many questions and many users, especially I just use simple method to insert the datas to database. I use form action and submit using POST.

I think, with convert the datas that I have submitted before to SQL file and upload it to server, will be better. But I don't know about that method. Or, maybe I can use other method or way ??

Need help, Sorry For My Poor english, And Thank You So Much.

Comment: 400 is not "many users", and 150 is not "so many questions", so don't worry and start dealing with any issue when you've correctly identified it through profiling. Also, it's not very clear what your actual problem is, nor your what's your idea...

Comment: Sure,, i have profilling the user. I just worried if many users submit form at the same time,, will it distrub the database or data consistent ??

Comment: @beben, depends whether you are inserting to one table or multiple. Basically database should stay in consistent state, but if you are inserting/modifying data on multiple tables in the same request, use transactions.

Comment: @EvaldasDzimanavicius transactions ?? like what ?? thx u...

Comment: I put the info about transactions in an answer as code cannot be formatted nicely in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep database in consistent state you should be using transactions (if you are inserting/updating data from multiple tables in one request).

```
$db->beginTransaction();
try 
{
    // insert data to first table
    // insert data to second table
    ...
    // insert data to last table

    $db->commit();                 
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    $db->rollBack();
}
```

This is an example using Zend, but the idea is the same with CodeIgniter. Maybe implementation (method names) are different.

CodeIgniter example:

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

Here you find more info about transactions with CodeIgniter:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html

Comment: So, transaction can keep the data consistent ?? and no worry if many users submit the form at the same time ?? And, when I insert the data to the database won't cause any problems ?? Thanks.

Comment: Transactions will make sure, that if one of your queries fails (for some reason) no other queries will be executed, they will be rolled back. In other words, all or nothing. 
As for multiple users submitting same form at the same time - it should not be a problem. Database engine will make sure, that multiple queries from multiple users will not interfere with each other.

Comment: Evaldas Dzimanavicius Ok... Thank You...  I know the point... :)